# Obtain the polynomial approximation of second and third degree least squares on the interval [−1,1]g(x)=ln(x+2)

Tags: real-analysis

Obtain the polynomial approximation of second and third degree least squares on the interval $ [-1,1 ] g(x) = ln(x+2)$ Additionally, calculate the error for each of the approximations.
Plot each approximation on a single graph for both the function $f$ and the function $g$.

For the polynomial of degree two I have done the following:
$P_2(x) = a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$

Then

$
a_0\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^0dx + a_1\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^1dx + a_2 \int_{-1}^{1}x^ 2dx = \int_{-1}^{1} ln(x+2)dx$

$a_0\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^1dx +a_1\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx + a_2 \int_{-1}^{1}x^ 3dx = \int_{-1}^{1} ln(x+2)dx$

$a_0\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx + a_1\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}x^3dx + a_2 \int_{-1}^{1}x^ 4dx = \int_{-1}^{1} ln(x+2)dx$

These were the systems of equations that I obtained:

$2a_0+a_1+\frac{2}{3}a_2= (3ln3)-2)$

$a_0+ \frac{2}{3}a_1+a_2= (3ln(3)-2$

$\frac{2}{3}a_0+a_1+\frac{2}{5}a_2= (3 ln(3)-2)$

IS Correct?